# Getting Image from Parse/Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am attempting to load an image stored in Parse; using code found in this tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/mealspotting I wrote this code:

```
 mProfileImage = mCurrentUser.getParseFile("ProfilePhoto");


        mProfilePhoto = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.meal_preview_image);




        mProfilePhoto.setParseFile(mProfileImage);
        mProfilePhoto.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                mProfilePhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

I have this in my layout:

```
<com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/meal_preview_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

I am using this `protected ParseImageView mProfilePhoto;`, a ParseImageView.  When I run the app, the image does not appear.

Comment: check if this is added in AndroidMenifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 2):

This is how i generally get `ImageUrl` and show it in `ImageView` which includes image caching mechanism too. You need parseObject.

```
String Imgurl;
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("ProfilePhoto"); 
if (image!=null) {
   Log.d("track", image.getUrl());
   Imgurl = image.getUrl();
}
```

Then use some image caching library like Universal Image Loader to avoid OutOfMemory exception and smooth scrolling.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(Imgurl, imageView);
```

Comment: I am getting an error: no static displayImage cannot be referenced from a static context..I added the Universal Image Loader, and followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267671/universal-imageloader-java-io-eofexception..where is imageLoader called?

Comment: You don't need to create the class. Visit github & type Universal Image Loader. You will be guided how to install and setup.